# How to know how much my scroller moved using pure Js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a `<div id="slide"></div>` on my web page it has a horizontal scroller bar below it(it also contain a slider).

So I want to know that how much(**in px**) my horizontal scroller bar  moves when the slider in that div scroll.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

```
jQuery('#slide').scrollLeft();
```